# Can I get concat() to ignore column names and work only based on the position of the columns?

Tags: python, pandas, append, concatenation

The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) , at least as of version 0.24.2, specify that pandas.concat can ignore the index, with ignore_index=True, but

> Note the index values on the other axes are still respected in the
>   join.

Is there a way to avoid this, i.e. **to concatenate based on the position only, and ignoring the names of the columns?**

I see two options:

- rename the columns so they match, or
- convert to numpy, concatenate in
  numpy, then from numpy back to pandas

**Are there more elegant ways?**

For example, if I want to add the series s as an additional row to the dataframe df, I can:

- convert s to frame
- transpose it
- rename its columns so they are the
  same as those of df
- concatenate

It works, but it seems very "un-pythonic"!

A toy example is below; this example is with a dataframe and a series, but the same concept applies with two dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['a']=[1]
df['x']='this'
df['y']='that'

s=pd.Series([3,'txt','more txt'])
st=s.to_frame().transpose()
st.columns=df.columns
out= pd.concat( [df, st] , axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Not sure I am following - isn't that just another way of renaming them?

Comment: For the case of 1 dataframe, 1 series. This seems more pythonic at least: `df.loc[df.shape[0], :] = s.values`

Comment: If you just want to add another row to a dataframe from a series, then @Alex-AntoineFortin's solution is perhaps the easiest method. It should be noted you can use any new name for the index value such as `df.loc['new_row', :] = s.values`.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. If you type it up as an answer, I'll upvote it and accept it. When instead it's two dataframes, I imagine there's no way around renaming or moving to numpy, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of 1 `dataframe` and 1 `series`, you can do:

> df.loc[df.shape[0], :] = s.values